Is completion of a abelian torsion free group again torsion free?
My question: Suppose $G$ is an abelian group which $p$-torsion free. Let $G=G_0 \supset G_1 \supset G_2 \dots $ be decreasing sequence of subgroups such that $\cap_{n=0}^{\infty} G_n =\{0\}$ then is the completion of $G$ always $p$-torsion free?
We know, if $G$ is abelian residually finite(i.e., intersection of subgroups of finite index is trivial) torsion free abelian group then the profinite completion $\hat{G}$ is also torsion free.

Use **text** for text.

No, this is not true. For example if $\def\Z{\mathbf{Z}}G=\Z$ and $G_n = p_1 \cdots p_n \Z$ where $p_1, p_2, \dots$ are the prime numbers then $G$ is torsion-free and yet the completion of $G$ with respect to $G_1, G_2, \dots$ is $$\lim_\longleftarrow G/G_n \cong \prod_p \Z/p\Z,$$ which has $p$-torsion for all $p$.

You are confusing the inverse limit and the direct product: Inverse limit is contained in the direct product, not equal to it.

@MoisheKohan I know the difference between the inverse limit and the direct product. The quotient $G/G_n$ is the product $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf{Z} / p_i \mathbf{Z}$ by CRT, and the connecting maps $G/G_n \to G/G_{n-1}$ are the obvious ones.

Oh, sorry, you are right, I did not read your answer carefully.
